# Centering cell entries in ctable

Tags: latex

Is there an easy way to center the cell entries in this table. The confidence interval look alright, but the estimate itself seems left-justified in the cell.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
        \usepackage{ctable}
        \usepackage{longtable}
        \begin{document}
        \ctable[ caption={compldich}, label=z, pos=!tbp, ]{lll} {} {\FL\multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Univariate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Multivariate}\NN
        \ML
        (Intercept)&&2.96 \NN
        &&(2.189,3.73)\NN
        \NN
        Age&-0.011 &-0.01\NN
        &(-0.017,-0.005)&(-0.017,-0.003)\NN
        \NN
        GenderFemale&0.142&0.143\NN
        & (-0.146,0.431)& (-0.177,0.464)\NN
        \NN
        HISSA&-1.299 &-1.385 \NN
        &(-1.608,-0.99)&(-1.71,-1.06)\NN
        \NN
        Ethan&-0.089 &-0.404\NN
        &(-0.374,0.195)& (-0.722,-0.086)\NN
        \FL
        }
        \end{document}
```

Comment: Check out http://tex.stackexchange.com ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't `{lll}` be `{lcc}` ?